# $T$ linear operator s.t. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n{=}0_X$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}T(x_n){=}0_Y$ then $T$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, solution-verification

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two normed spaces, with $X$ a reflexive space.
I suppone that $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is an operator such that:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n{=}0_X$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}T(x_n){=}0_Y$.

I have to prove that $T$ is bounded.

Here is my attempt:

If $X$ is reflexive, I know that every bounded sequences in $X$ have a subsequence $\{ x_{n_k} \}$ such that $T(\{ x_{n_k} \})$ converges in $Y$.

For the sake of contradiction I assume that $T$ is not bounded so there exists a vector $y_n$
such that $\| y_n\| \leq 1$ but $ \| T y_n\| > n^3$. Now let $x_n=\frac{1}{n} y_n$.

I have proved in this way that exists a sequence $ (x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $ X $ that converges in norm to $ 0_{X} $ (therefore $(x_n)$ is bounded)  but for which $ \| T(x_{n}) \|_{Y} \geq n^{2} $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. So I have a contraddiction

Is my solution correct?

Moreover I was wondering if it necessary here the hypothesis that $X$ is a reflexive space. Is there a way to prove this proposition without it?

Any help  will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fear that from the hypothesis that $X$ is reflexive I cannot conclude what I have said.... I can only say that a bounded sequence in X has a weakly convergent subsequence...is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say in the comments, you cannot assume a convergent subsequence exists. However, your proof can be salvaged. There is no need to assume reflexivity of $X$ or compactness of $T$. Assume that $T$ is not bounded. Then there is a sequence of unit vectors $(x_n)$ such that $\|Tx_n\|\ge n$ for alle $n$, that is $\|T\frac{x_n}{n}\|\ge 1$ for alle $n$. But since $x_n$ is a unit vector for all $n$, we must have $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_n}{n}=0$, so by assumption $\lim_{n\to \infty} T\frac{x_n}{n}=0$ and we obtain a contradiction.

Comment: This proof is of course only a minor modification of the original proof.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming the operator $T$ is continuous at $0_X$. In a normed linear space, if an operator $T$ is continuous at $0_X$, then it is continuous (bounded) on $X$. This is a standard theorem in functional analysis.